# Is Java web application unavailable while Wildfly is replacing a deployment?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have a java web application and I uploaded it to Wildfly server by Admin Console. After that, I replaced in deployments section the same web application and it takes 15 seconds approximately. The question is that while it is replacing in those 15 seconds, the web application is unavailable for users?

Comment: Can you describe your deployment a bit? Is it large in size? Are you including a lot of dependencies?

Comment: I got a webapp by Netbeans project. Then I apply Clean and Build. After that, I go to Wildfly admin Console->Deployments. I press Add button and select the War file where is located in project target folder. The War file has a size of 50MB aproximately or little more.

Comment: Are you including the Jakarta EE specification libraries? That's not too big, but if you include those that may reduce the size by excluding them and allow a faster deployment.